# запускаю pipline gitlab на своем компьютере локально (runner находится на компьютере) но мне пишут ошибки что не найдены команды?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-runner, ci-cd

Я пишу pipline на gitlab и мне надо положить версию, которую я указываю в тэге при коммите таким образом: `git tag 1.8.21`
Раньше использовал команду для этого `$ TAG=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $CI_COMMIT_SHA)`
Но потом поменял gitlab-runner на тот который установил на компьютере своем и перестало работать, начало появляться вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом попробовал `$ TAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)` и получил все ту же ошибку. Можете пожалуйста посоветовать команду для получения версии?

**Дополнение**
Понял в чем ошибка но не знаю как исправить подскажите пожалуйста. Ошибка сообщает что не может найти команду которую я пишу (попробовал написать python --version и та же самая ошибка). На компьютере (pipline запускается локально на моей машине) установлено все что пытаюсь использовать в частности python, в чем может быть проблема?